# How to print html part by part?

Tags: php

I have page which it took long time to process and i want it to print result in web page for example every thousand time that loop run and i don't want to use java script.
my code is :

```
<?php
echo " it start at : ".date('H:i:s');
for ($j = 0 ; $j < 100000 ; $j++ ){
  if ($j % 1000 == 0)
    Print $j
  //do some thing
}
echo " it end at : ".date('H:i:s');
?>
```

First problem is it wait until end and second problem is it don't understand every 1000 times and it never get 0 value.

What should i do ?

Comment: echo " it end at : ".$date = date('H:i:s');

Answer (score 0):

Do not loop in single increments, loop in increments of 1000 if thats what you require:

```
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $numberHigherThan1000 ; $j+=1000 ){
    echo $j
}
```